# How to use Streamlit on Sagemaker Studio with an image terminal?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, streamlit, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have been trying to test a streamlit app on Sagemaker Studio.

If I run the `streamlit hello` command on the system terminal, the command executes properly and I'm able to access the app at

`https://x-xxxxxxxxxxxx.studio.us-west-2.sagemaker.aws/jupyter/default/proxy/8501/`

When I run the same command through an image terminal, I get the `500 : Internal Server Error` at the same link. Is there any way to use streamlit with an image terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SageMaker Studio architecture at this moment doesn't allow you to run apps through Jupyter Proxy on a kernel gateway. Therefore, running Streamlit in an image terminal is a little bit tricky.

One of the options is to use [SageMaker SSH Helper](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper) library. After reading and completing the "Getting Started" section, you will need to jump to the "Local IDE integration with SageMaker Studio over SSH". Inside the script `sm-local-ssh-ide` there are [lines with the port forwarding instructions](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-ssh-helper/blob/v1.10.1/sagemaker_ssh_helper/sm-local-ssh-ide#L40_L44) for the SSH client.

You will need to add one more:

```
 -L localhost:8501:localhost:8501 \
```

After you complete all steps and run this script, your Streamlit app that you've started inside the SageMaker Studio image terminal will be available on your local machine at http://localhost:8501/.

If you want to learn more how SageMaker Studio works, I recommend this nice blog post by Giuseppe Angelo Porcelli and Vikesh Pandey: [Dive deep into Amazon SageMaker Studio Notebooks architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/dive-deep-into-amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebook-architecture/).